# WinForms Datagridview change image row at runtime vs 2010

Tags: winforms, datagridview

Never used the datagridview before and I cannot figure out how to change myImageColumn depending on status.

I am loading some logs in this grid and again depending on the status I would like to assign the appriopriate image.Not sure which event I should be doing it.
Any suggestions or example with bound or unbound would be great.

Here is some code

```
public enum LogType
{
    Fatal,
    Error,
    Warn,
    Info,
    Debug,
    None,
}
public class Log
{

    public LogType LogType { get; internal set; }
    public string Message { get;  set; }
}



    private void LoadDataGrid()
    {
        // Create the image column.
        DataGridViewImageColumn imageCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        imageCol.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        imageCol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal;
        imageCol.Frozen = true;
        imageCol.Name = "Image";
        imageCol.HeaderText = "";
        imageCol.DisplayIndex = 0;
        imageCol.Image = Properties.Resources.warning;

        datagrid.Columns.Add(imageCol);


        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colMessage = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colMessage.Name = "Message";
        colMessage.HeaderText = "Message";
        datagrid.Columns.Add(colMessage);

         datagrid.DataSource=   GetAllLogs();
    }

     private void OnCellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
    //I am not sure about the all thing here
        // Check if it's the Image column.
        if ((dgvLogs.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Image"))
        {
            object value = dgvLogs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["LogType"].Value;

            //TODO:Convert to enum 
            // switch (type)
        //{
          //  case "fatal":  e.Value=FatalImage;
           // case "error": e.Value=ErrorImage;
            //case "warn":  e.Value=WarnImage;
            //case "info": e.Value=InfoImage;
            //case "debug":  e.Value=DebugImage;

        //}
    }
```

Need help with some code here or link where you can see how images are determined at runtime.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a link which maybe helpful for you.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=446453&seqNum=14

Hth.